# Hotkeys in a minimized Tkinter-based program

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, hotkeys

I am making a hack for a game, and I want to start/stop the script with the F7 hotkey while the game is running at full screen. I've tried to use `root.bind` and `pynput` to do it, but none of them worked.

Here is my code:

```
hack_running = False


def hack():
    if  hack_running:
        PressKeyPynput(0x02)
        time.sleep(0.08)
        ReleaseKeyPynput(0x02)
        PressKeyPynput(0x11)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        ReleaseKeyPynput(0x11)
        PressKeyPynput(0x1F)
        time.sleep(0.6)
        ReleaseKeyPynput(0x1F)
        PressKeyPynput(0x02)
        time.sleep(0.08)
        ReleaseKeyPynput(0x02)
        root.after(900000, hack)

def Start_stop():
    global hack_running
    if Startk['text'] == 'Start':
        hack_running = True
        hack()
        Startk.config(text='Stop')
    else:
        hack_running = False
        Startk.config(text='Start')


root = tk.Tk()

root.resizable(False, False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

Startk = tk.Button(frame, text='Start', font=("Calibri", 10), command=Start_stop)
Startk.pack(side='top', pady='50')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***while the game is running full screen***:  This is contradiction to your questions title? Read up on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) and 
[Tkinter.Widget.bind-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bind-method)

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pynput:

```
import pynput

def run():
    print('f7') # your code

def press(key):
    if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.f7:
        run()

pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=press).run()
```

For keyboard combinations see [this github issue](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/20).
Hope that's helpful!

Comment: I worked, but now the gui won't run, that is what happened when i tried another method with pynput

Comment: That's because you've started a listener. Once uou use `.run()`, it will pause the program at that point. Try using `.start()`, not`.run()`.

Answer (score 2):

Pynput has an easy class which provide hotkey function called `GlobalHotKeys`.[Reference here.](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#global-hotkeys)

---

Unfortunately,if there is only python,I think it couldn't do more if you want to make it work in game.

Normally, there are also keyboard listener thread in game.When your python script work with your game together,they will cause conflict.And your python script couldn't work normally.(And game will always take some measures to prevent cheating.)

As far as I know,`AutoHotkey` script could work in game(at least it worked for me in the past).[AutoHotkey Official document](http://ahkcn.sourceforge.net/docs/AutoHotkey.htm).On `macOS`,[refer this](https://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/?platform=mac)

Comment: The only problem would be that autohotkey is not so multiplatform.

Comment: @БогданОпир You are surely correct,but I think there are fewer people will play game on `linux`.

Comment: There are less linux gamers, but at the first place, autohotkey is not a programatical solution, so doesn't belong to SO, and secondly the solution should work for most future users, not only gamers / windows users. If this was the only answer, I think that the literal same question without the *gaming* context wouldn't be considered a duplicate, will it?

Comment: @БогданОпир I am not sure this is the only answer.I have mentioned the class `GlobalHotKeys`,if using `GlobalHotKeys` also couldn't work so I think only tkinter and pynput couldn't do it well.Maybe there are some tricks really work.